# How to multiply 2x SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, join

I use 2 query. First ruturn wall's price, second return wall'surface.

First

```
SELECT s.pole AS SURFACE from sciana s natural join praca p where s.sciana_id=p.sciana_id
```

Second

```
SELECT u.usluga_cena AS PRICE from usluga u natural join praca p where u.usluga_id=p.usluga_id
```

I have to create query, wchich return table SURFACE * PRICE.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT s.pole * u.usluga_cena AS MultipliedOut
FROM sciana s 
  JOIN praca p ON s.sciana_id = p.sciana_id
  JOIN usluga u ON u.usluga_id = p.usluga_id
```